# which country to visit first while two different country tourist visa in my passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, tourist-visas, ireland, bangladeshi-citizens

The question might be silly, but I just need to know. Please help.

I am a Bangladeshi ordinary citizen, hence Bangladeshi passport holder.

I applied for Irish short stay(90 days)visit visa and got the visa and allowed to land Ireland anytime between 10 Feb to 9 May,( single entry), and after landing Ireland, they will allow me to stay for next 90 days.

After getting this above mentioned Irish visa, I have applied for an Indian tourist visa and also got 1-year multiple entry Indian Tourist visa.

My question is: Can I first come to India and stay a few days and then catch my flight from Calcutta/Delhi to Dublin?

Will there be any problem of immigration at Calcutta/Delhi?

I have no issues with my earlier visas, passport etc.

Based on this, I will book my flight to Dublin. :D :D

Thanks.

Comment: Ireland doesn’t care where you arrive from, only that you have a valid visa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of visas in your passport does not matter, neither the order in which you obtained them, as long as you travel on correct dates to corresponding countries. Having unopened (or even unused) visa in a passport will not be a problem.